# Migrate users from one AAD B2C tenant another B2C tenant including password

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I would like to migrate users from one Azure AD B2C tenant to another B2C tenant including the credentials: the email address and the password.

Migrating the username wouldn't be a problem with custom code, but is it possible to also migrate the password to another tenant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is on a per user basis using [Seamless migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration#seamless-migration). Each user will have to login in the new tenant which will communicate trough a [custom ROPC policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc?tabs=applications) with the old one and do the migration.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible now, please check [this MS link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-migration) on user migration. MS has a sample APP [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-dotnetcore-b2c-account-management) on GitHub, which needs some tweaks though, to do the job.

```
Command  Description
====================
[1]      Get all users (one page)
[2]      Get user by object ID
[3]      Get user by sign-in name
[4]      Delete user by object ID
[5]      Update user password
[6]      Create users (bulk import)
[7]      Create user with custom attributes and show result
[8]      Get all users (one page) with custom attributes
[help]   Show available commands
[exit]   Exit the program
-------------------------
```

Comment: Hmm I don't see "bulk import"... only "bulk invite". Which seems to send users invitations instaed of directly create them. Did they change it?